# Google Charts: Setting padding for the hAxis

Tags: google-visualization

My chart is working fine as expected except that the hAxis labels have very little or no padding in between the chart itself and the legend. Is there a way to increase it?

options:

```
var options = {
          colors:['rgb(32, 170, 188)', 'rgb(32, 188, 77)'],
          lineWidth:4,
          areaOpacity: 0.15,
          width:$(window).width() * 0.5,
          height:$(window).width() * 0.25,
          animation: {
               "startup": true,
               duration: 1200,
               easing: 'out',
          },
          fontName: 'Open Sans',
          legend: {
            position:'bottom',
          },
          chartArea:{
            width:'90%',
            height:'80%',
          }
        };
```

[image: chart]

Comment: does decreasing `chartArea.height` help?

Comment: @WhiteHat - thanks for the suggestion, I tried, but it does not.

Comment: I don't know exactly what they meant, but in some issues the google chart team has mentioned that font sizing is poorly calculated if the chart is drawn into a hidden element. Might that be the case here?

Answer (score 0):

only option I can think of, would be to modify the labels once the chart is `'ready'`,
or on `'animationfinish'`

in this example, the `y` position is increased by `4`

looks kind of *jumpy* with the animation,
there may be other options, if you know svg

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'callback': function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2013',  1000,      400],
      ['2014',  1170,      460],
      ['2015',  660,       1120],
      ['2016',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      colors:['rgb(32, 170, 188)', 'rgb(32, 188, 77)'],
      lineWidth:4,
      animation: {
        startup: true,
        duration: 1200,
        easing: 'out',
      },
      areaOpacity: 0.15,
      fontName: 'Open Sans',
      legend: {
        position:'bottom',
      },
      chartArea:{
      }
    };

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'animationfinish', moveLabels);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', moveLabels);

    function moveLabels() {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (label) {
        if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
          label.setAttribute('y', parseFloat(label.getAttribute('y')) + 4);
        }
      });
    }

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  'packages':['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```